# A compass that points to a specific city

Tags: android, compass

I recently started developing an app in Android Studio, the app contains a compass. Everything works for me, now I have been instructed to change the compass not to point north but to specific coordinates.
for example:
The arrow will point in the direction of the coordinates: 31.77682832908305, 35.234508502967

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You will have to use the current GPS coordinates and the current heading (relative to the north pole). Then you can calculate the compass heading based on the citys GPS coordinates. Can you share your current code?

Comment: this is my code: https://www.wlsdevelop.com/en/2016/12/08/how-to-create-a-compass-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the destination 's longitude is less than your current location's longitude, point the compass to left (i.e., west)
or else right, (i.e.., east )

if the destination 's latitude is less than your current location's latitude , point the compass to top (i.e.., north)
or else bottom, (i.e.., south)

have a look at
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action
which gives you path- direction from source to destination and tune it up..